# Javascript click "event" passed to a function for click location

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somewhere in the HTML there is an input. When the input is clicked the event should be passed to a function to get the clicked location.

```
<input type=".." onclick="namespace.aFunction("param", event)" />

(function (namespace, $, undefined) {
    namespace.aFunction = function(string, event) {
        var clickX;
        var clickY;

        // IE Only
        var e = window.event || e;
        clickX = e.clientX;
        clickY = e.clientY;
        //... alert to debug or do something
    };
} (window.namespace = window.namespace || {}, jQuery));
```

Passing "this" didn't help in IE. Is there a good way to get the click event to get the location of the clicked item that works cross browser etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This began working in IE after deleting the cache so this seems to work. The event parameter had been null after I added it but it was just due to the change not refreshing in the browser.

```
<input type=".." onclick="namespace.aFunction("param", event)" />

(function (namespace, $, undefined) {
    namespace.aFunction = function(string, event) {
        var clickX;
        var clickY;

        if (event != 'undefined' && event != null && event.clientX != null && event.clientY != null) {
            clickX = event.clientX;
            clickY = event.clientY;
            //... alert to debug or do something
        }
    };
} (window.namespace = window.namespace || {}, jQuery));
```